# recording screen and webcam to video file

Tags: java, webcam, jmf, video-recording, screen-recording

I'm trying to create an application to record screen of user or from webcam and save into an video file.

I tried Java Media Framework to make it work but It's fail in Windows 64 bit.
 I found that Java Media Framework is quite old and it isn't supported now :(

My question is: 
  Are there any another library help us record screen and video from Webcam ?
 If Java is not supported, What language could help?

I found some application have same feature: 
   + http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/
   + http://www.apowersoft.com/free-online-screen-recorder
 It's java applet that user can download from server without installing.

Thank you in advanced !

**Update:**
 I'm finding another solution in HTML5

Update: 2013/07/05**
 I found WebRTC 1.0 can reach the solution but Google Chrome hasn't suport Media Stream Recorder yet.

Answer (score 2):

i have a sample code to record the screen by using com.xuggle package

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaWriter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec;

public class ScreenRecordingExample {

    private static final double FRAME_RATE = 50;

private static final int SECONDS_TO_RUN_FOR = 20;

    private static final String outputFilename = "c:/mydesktop.mp4";

    private static Dimension screenBounds;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // let's make a IMediaWriter to write the file.
    final IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(outputFilename);

        screenBounds = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        // We tell it we're going to add one video stream, with id 0,
        // at position 0, and that it will have a fixed frame rate of FRAME_RATE.
        writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MPEG4, 
                   screenBounds.width/2, screenBounds.height/2);

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        for (int index = 0; index < SECONDS_TO_RUN_FOR * FRAME_RATE; index++) {

            // take the screen shot
            BufferedImage screen = getDesktopScreenshot();

            // convert to the right image type
            BufferedImage bgrScreen = convertToType(screen, 
               BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

            // encode the image to stream #0
            writer.encodeVideo(0, bgrScreen, System.nanoTime() - startTime, 
                   TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

            // sleep for frame rate milliseconds
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) (1000 / FRAME_RATE));
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // ignore
            }

        }

        // tell the writer to close and write the trailer if  needed
        writer.close();

    }

    public static BufferedImage convertToType(BufferedImage sourceImage, int targetType) {

        BufferedImage image;

        // if the source image is already the target type, return the source image
        if (sourceImage.getType() == targetType) {
            image = sourceImage;
        }
        // otherwise create a new image of the target type and draw the new image
        else {
            image = new BufferedImage(sourceImage.getWidth(), 
                 sourceImage.getHeight(), targetType);
        image.getGraphics().drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, null);
        }

        return image;

    }

    private static BufferedImage getDesktopScreenshot() {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
        Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(screenBounds);
        return robot.createScreenCapture(captureSize);
        } 
        catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it is kind of slow and ugly. This solution is posted all over the web but in my case, video is not played well on vlc nor on mplayer. I am on Fedora.